# How to find the angle between two locations defined by latitude or longitude using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find out the angle between two location defined by latitude and longitude using javascript.

suppose i have two points like this :-

```
pt1 = 12.92436858, 77.64480728, pt2 = 12.92402417, 77.64389674
```

so how to get the angle between these two points ?

Comment: It takes three points to define an angle. Two points define a line and only have a distance between them.  For an angle, you would need to be asking about the angle between that line and something else.  If you mean how do you define a bearing (e.g. a compass direction) based on two points as compared to true the North direction, then see the post referenced in Jayram's comment.